# Can't get Scrapy to return text in Div

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm having trouble getting scrapy to return the text from this div.  When it does return data its considerably more than what I thought it would return.

Target HTML:

```
<div class="DivTimeSpan" title="Full Time">12:00 PM - 09:00 PM </div>
```

Attempt 1:

```
    def parse_schedule(self, response):
    s_item = ScheduleItem()

    for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='DivTimeSpan']"):
        s_item['schedule'] = sel.select('//text()').extract()
    return s_item
```

Returns:

> "\r\n\r\n    ", "\r\n        ", "\r\n            \r\n\r\n            var allowedUrls = [];\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"Login.net\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"Login\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"AccountLogin.net\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"AccountLogin\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"CreateAccount\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"CreateAccount.net\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"UpdateAccount\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"UpdateAccount.net\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"CreateResellersAccount\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"CreateResellersAccount.net\");\r\n            allowedUrls.push(\"CreateQqestSAASAccount\");\r\n
>   "11:00 AM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM"

The entire file is probably thousands of lines long and contains what looks like text from outside of the div I specified

I understood //text() to return the text of the element and its children.  The html element I'm targeting doesn't have any children though so I assumed it would only return the data in the div.

Next I tried just using "/text()". This was the only change

Attempt 2:

```
    for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='DivTimeSpan']"):
        s_item['schedule'] = sel.select('/text()').extract()
    return s_item
```

Returns:

> [{"schedule": []}]

Desired Result:

> [{"schedule": ["11:00 AM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM
>   - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM", "12:00 PM - 09:00 PM"]}]

The url I'm scraping is behind a company login so I can't give out the actual url.

Elisha's post lead me in the right direction, Thanks!!! :)
Answer:

```
for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='DivTimeSpan']"):
    s_item['schedule'] = map(unicode.strip,    sel.select('//div/text()').extract())
return s_item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second attempt is closer to extracting the value. Yet, you need to extract the text from the node, and not from the document root:

```
s_item['schedule'] = sel.select('/div/text()').extract()[0]
```

In case the document contains more tags (which are not *div*s), you can try:

```
s_item['schedule'] = sel.select('//div/text()').extract()[0]
```